# In Rails Controller testing, is there a way to pass query (non-routing) parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm writing controller tests in Rails and RSpec, and it seems from reading the source code of `ActionController::TestCase` that it's not possible to pass arbitrary query parameters to the controller -- only routing parameters.

To work around this limitation, I am currently using `with_routing`:

```
with_routing do |routes|
  # this nonsense is necessary because
  # Rails controller testing does not
  # pass on query params, only routing params

  routes.draw do 
    get '/users/confirmation/:confirmation_token' => 'user_confirmations#show'
    root :to => 'root#index'
  end

  get :show, 'confirmation_token' => CONFIRMATION_TOKEN
end
```

As you may be able to guess, I am testing a custom Confirmations controller for Devise. This means I am jacking into an existing API and do not have the option to change how the real mapping in `config/routes.rb` is done.

Is there a neater way to do this? A supported way for `get` to pass query parameters?

---

EDIT: There *is* something else going on. I created a minimal example in https://github.com/clacke/so_13866283 :

`spec/controllers/receive_query_param_controller_spec.rb`

```
describe ReceiveQueryParamController do
  describe '#please' do
    it 'receives query param, sets @my_param' do
      get :please, :my_param => 'test_value'
      assigns(:my_param).should eq 'test_value'
    end
  end  
end
```

`app/controllers/receive_query_param_controller.rb`

```
class ReceiveQueryParamController < ApplicationController
  def please
    @my_param = params[:my_param]
  end
end
```

`config/routes.rb`

```
So13866283::Application.routes.draw do
  get '/receive_query_param/please' => 'receive_query_param#please'
end
```

This test passes, so I suppose it is Devise that does something funky with the routing.

---

EDIT:

Pinned down where in Devise routes are defined, and updated my example app to match it.

```
So13866283::Application.routes.draw do
  resource :receive_query_param, :only => [:show],
    :controller => "receive_query_param"
end
```

... and spec and controller updated accordingly to use `#show`. The test still passes, i.e. `params[:my_param]` is populated by `get :show, :my_param => 'blah'`. So, still a mystery why this does not happen in my real app.

Comment: Not the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665743/query-parameters-and-assert-generates-assert-routing-what-am-i-missing -- that one is about route testing. But I will see if I can learn something from it, if "extras" can be used with `get` as well.

Comment: This line, if any, holds the key: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.8/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L148 ... if I could only find out where that `query_parameters` is defined and how I can populate it.

Comment: Next step in the chain is that `GET` and its alias `query_parameters` are defined in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.8/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb#L224 and override the `GET` in `Rack::Request`.

Answer (score 3):

Controller tests don't route. You are unit-testing the controller--routing is outside its scope.

A typical controller spec example tests an action:

```
describe MyController do
  it "is successful" do
    get :index
    response.status.should == 200
  end
end
```

You set up the test context by passing parameters to `get`, e.g.:

```
  get :show, :id => 1
```

You can pass query parameters in that hash.

If you *do* want to test routing, you can write routing specs, or request (integration) specs.

Comment: I am testing the controller, not the routing. Unfortunately Rails is not letting me send the parameters I want, because *it* is entangling routing and controller testing. That's why I need the `with_routing`.

Comment: I think I see what's going on here. You've defined a resource that requires an id in the params hash, but you're not passing it in the spec. You should be able to simply pass both the id and any additional query params in that hash *as long as the id is present*. viz: `{ :id => "1", :hello => "world" }`

Comment: No, the existing routing does not require an `:id` and there is no error message. `get` simply does not pass any parameters I give it, unless those parameters are in the routing path.

Comment: Are you *sure* `get :show` does not require an :id? How is the route defined?

Comment: `rake routes CONTROLLER=user_confirmations` gives me `GET  /users/confirmation(.:format)     user_confirmations#show`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21167/discussion-between-clacke-and-zetetic)

Comment: I updated the question with a minimal app that tries to reproduce the problem, but fails. It's all very mysterious. Devise defines the route with a `resource :blah, :only => [:show]`, and it loses the query param, but when I do the same I can feed it a query param without taking any special measures.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there isn't something else going on?  I have a Rails 3.0.x project and am passing parameters.. well.. this is a post.. maybe it's different for get, but that seems odd..

```
before  { post :contact_us, :contact_us => {:email => 'joe@example.com',
         :category => 'Category', :subject => 'Subject', :message => 'Message'} }
```

The above is definitely being used in my controller in the  `params` object.

Comment: Yes, I believe a post is handled differently. The code is simply biased against get query parameters, the "rails way" is to pass things as part of the path, apparently. I will check how Devise tests itself, maybe there are clues there.

Comment: Oh, Devise only does integration testing for this controller, so then this issue does not show up.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing this now:

```
@request.env['QUERY_STRING'] = "confirmation_token=" # otherwise it's ignored
get :show, :confirmation_token => CONFIRMATION_TOKEN
```

... but it looks hacky.

If someone could show me a neat and official way to do this, I would be delighted. Judging from what I've seen in the source code of `#get` and everything it calls, there doesn't seem to be any other way, but I'm hoping I overlooked something.